# Why is force constant inversely proportional to the length of spring?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When a body is deformed within elastic limit, restoring force acts and tries to bring it to original shape and size. The restoring force is electromagnetic in origin, having to do with atomic/molecular interactions. So why does the restoring force depend on the length of the spring?

Comment: To leading order approximation the potential is harmonic around the minimum equilibrium position. Beyond that you have to add higher order terms.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: For a longer wire, a given total displacement requires a smaller *per-atom* displacement. Therefore, the restoring force is lower. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: @Chemomechanics, your comment is an answer.